# Can we set the name of db table as variable in queries in Ruby using SQLite3?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sqlite

I am new in Ruby on Rails, so forgive me if my question is too obvious.
Depending on my knowledge for databases, I am not able doing the following, but I have not work this domain recently.

What I want to do is the following:

I have a table which is called Patients, which has the fields, disease and city.

I want to implement the following query:

```
Patient.select(city:"Paris")
```

Can I set the name of the table as a variable to this select statement?

Thank you

Comment: Do you mean you want to select all patients from the city "Paris"? In that case you want: Patient.where(city: "Paris")

Comment: no I mean I want to set as a variable the Patient.. is this possible? referring the name of the table

Comment: Is this possible?                                                                                                               var = Patient   and then var.select(city: "Paris")

Comment: Do you want to chain together a number of queries or pass the relation into a method? If so you could use var = Patient.scoped. Maybe you should explain what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: Did you figure this out?

Comment: @Ectoras can you please select my answer so it may be helpful for others thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this

```
table_name = "Patient"
table_name.constantize.select(city:"Paris")
```

Answer (score 0):

[`eval`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.1/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) could be used here as well:

```
> object_type = "Patient"
> query = "#{object_type}.select(city:'Paris')"
> eval(query)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think based on the comments you are wanting to pass round a relation object. You can do that with the scoped method. Ryan Bates has an excellent rails cast on using them: http://railscasts.com/episodes/112-anonymous-scopes

In your case you'd do:

```
scope = Patient.scoped
scope = scope.where(city: "Paris")
# ... other query options perhaps..eg
scope = scope.where(name: "John")
scope = scope.limit(10)
scope.all # => first 10 Patients from Paris named John
```